# How to setup cookie free domain for wp-includes?

Tags: cookies

I setup a cookie free domain and pointed  the `wp-content` folder to it

in config added

```
define("WP_CONTENT_URL", "https://static.domainname.com");

define("COOKIE_DOMAIN", "www.domainname.com");
```

all theme css/js files and images now point to

```
https://static.domainname.com/wp-content/file_path.file_ext
```

but the wp-includes files point to the default domain

[image]

is there a way to setup a cookie free for those ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @MaxYudin https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/wordpress/wordpress-how-to-serve-static-content-from-a-cookieless-domain/

Comment: Just dequeue local jQuery and enqueue it from the cookieless domain such as [Google Hosted Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery). It will be already gzipped too.

Comment: we should not have go trough theme files and dependencies to do this.

Comment: @MaxYudin using cookie free domains improves the website speed